# PHP $_SESSION and function on external file

Tags: php, function, session

I am developing a website, I have one file, i will call it "`main.php`", and a php file "`lib.php`", `lib.php` contain a function "`myfunction()`", wich try to access to current `$_SESSION` to read certain arrays. This function is called from `main.php`.

Need I pass the `$_SESSION` as a variable of the function?, I'm trying both read pass as a variable `$_SESSION` and without pass it, I can read the `$_SESSION` content

Thanks you in advance

Comment: $_SESSION is a [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) you don't need to parse it as an argument

Comment: Passing $_SESSION as a parameter would be a better choice as dependency would be eliminated.

Comment: @JA what do you mean by that?

Comment: @FordFiler, Big picture: if the OP requires to reuse the particular function where $_SESSION isn't available (e.g API/REST) it would be wise not to get dependant on SESSION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION is what PHP calls a superglobal.  What that means is that it can be accessed (it is in scope) from global scope and from any method, both inside and outside of a class.

You can read more about PHP's superglobals here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `$_SESSION`, just call `session_start();` on any page you want to use it